# grant a user of the ArcGIS server a publisher privileges

Tags: arcgis-server

Can I grant a user of the ArcGIS server a publisher privileges and prevent him from publishing service or at least do some restrictions on what he can publish?

Comment: You need to set new role I guess. Please check http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/administer/linux/adding-a-new-role-in-manager.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A publisher can publish anything. You can not restrict him from publishing specific services.

Here are a list of the things a publisher **is allowed** to do in Manager:

- Create and delete folders.
- View, publish, and delete services.
- Start, stop, and edit services.
- Set permissions rules about who can view services.
- Deploy and undeploy server object extensions (SOEs).
- View security configuration settings (for example, which type of role store is being used).
- View available users and the roles to which each user belongs.
- View available roles, the users who belong to each role, and the privileges assigned to each role.
- View and query logs.
- Create KML network links.
- View software authorization information.
- Register databases and data directories with the server.

and what he is **not allowed** to do:

- Edit the configuration store location.
- View, create, and edit clusters and their participating machines.
- Add and remove machines from the site.
- Start or stop a machine's participation in a site.
- Register and unregister server directories.
- Unregister Web Adaptors with the site.
- Edit security configuration settings (for example, which type of role store is being used).
- Add and remove users.
- Add and remove roles.
- Add and remove users from roles.
- Assign and revoke privileges on roles.
- Edit the primary site administrator.
- Edit log settings.
- Enable or disable automatic data copying when publishing to the server